# Is there any way to edit the dconf settings of GTK on a WindowsNT Install?

Tags: windows, gtk

I am trying to help the OP of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28157314/1695680

And I suspect their gtk install has some default settings that are undesirable. On Linux I believe these settings are kept in dconf, First are they kept in a dconf database for windows, or elsewhere (Like maybe ported to the Windows registry)?

Secondly, How can these values be inspected and edited? Similar to how the dconf-editor works on Linux.

*Note: At this time, Google results for `dconf-editor windows binary` show no obvious ports of dconf to windows. But if such a thing were to exist, I would like to be directed to it.*

Comment: "dconf" in windows is called "registry" ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind Are you sure that GTK uses the windows registry on a windows install? Can you link to that documentation to point out the gtk root in the windows registry?

Comment: No just saying: *the equivalent to dconf would be registry*. I would not assume the windows version to port dconf. I'd expect it to use a DLL or the registry (though the latter would make it less portable).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like at least with some Gnome/GTK/GSettings applications you can find gconf settings in the Windows registry.  I was playing with Meld and wanted to check something with [the Inspector](https://blog.gtk.org/2017/04/05/the-gtk-inspector/) and was able to enable it by setting:

```
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\GSettings\org\gtk\settings\debug /v enable-inspector-keybinding /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```